# How to get more than one record?

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am using JDBC with logstash to get data from a PostgreSQL query and export it to ES v7 here is the configuration file:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://ldatabase_rds_path?useSSL=true"
        jdbc_user => "username"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/z/Documents/postgresql-42.2.18.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        tracking_column => "id"
        tracking_column_type => "numeric"
         clean_run => true
        schedule => "0 */1 * * *"
        statement => "SELECT id as id, type as type, z_id as z_id, sender_id as sender_id, receiver_id as receiver_id, status as status, amount as amount, fees as fees, created as created, metadata as metadata, funding_source_from_id as funding_source_from_id, funding_source_to_id as funding_source_to_id, is_parent as is_parent, destination_type as destination_type, source_type as source_type FROM payments_transfer"
    }
}
output {
        stdout { codec => json_lines }
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                manage_template => false
                index => "payments_transfer_data"
                document_id => "%{id}"
         }
}
```

It take much time to only get 1 record from the database!
I tried some solutions like explicitly define a mapping so I added a mapping for the data like that:

```
PUT payments_transfer_data/_mapping/doc?include_type_name=true
{
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "@version": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "amount": {
      "type": "float"
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "destination_type": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "z_id": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "fees": {
      "type": "float"
    },
    "funding_source_from_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "funding_source_to_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "is_parent": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "receiver_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "sender_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "source_type": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the only record that get:

```
    source_type:customer sender_id:3 destination_type:funding-source type:funded_transfer z_id:863a240c-2011-e911-8114-bacd823e9f1d receiver_id:65 status:processed amount:550 funding_source_from_id:332 @timestamp:Nov 8, 2020 @ 16:00:08.809 fees:5.61 is_parent:false created:Jan 5, 2019 @ 21:28:21.847 @version:1 id:2,160 funding_source_to_id: - metadata: - _id:2160 _type:doc _index:payments_transfer_data _score: -
```

Comment: What's the result set and it's size when you run same query on postgres db?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation you should use `tracking_column` in conjunction to [use_column_value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-use_column_value). With your current setting `tracking_column` will not have any impact.

Have you tried using `Select * from` to see if everything is being pulled.

Comment: I added the tracking_column to true and tried select *, but it gives the same output.